# how to check the charecter who is used for split the string;

Tags: c#

i have a string ex:

```
string word =     "Background-color:red;"
```

don't be confused i am not talking about css

i split the word by `"-"`

now i forget what thing i used for split the word and

two thing first split result

```
Background [0]
color:red; [1]
```

and

```
 string word =     "Background-color:red;"
```

how can i check the character who used for split the word in this example split by `"-"`

are any trick exist to do this in c#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Once the words have been split out into an array, the information of *how* they got there is gone. Arrays do not contain information on how they were created.

If you want to store the character you have used for splitting the string, you need to do so yourself.

Of course, if you have to original string, you can check against the strings in the array to find the characters in the original that are not in any of the strings in the array.

Don't forget that [split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) takes an array of either `char` or `string` to split by, so you may have more than one character/string that have been split by.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to both the original word and the array result of the splitting, then the splitting character will be found at:

```
word[split[0].Length]
```

If the split did not actually split (for instance, `split[0] == word`), you cannot determine the splitting character at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda wild but here is some idea
Where you see [0] and [1] is whatever the content of your splited array at that given position.

```
string splitString = word.Substring(word.IndexOf([0]) + [0].Length,word.IndexOf([1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string word =  "Background-color:red;";
string[] arr = word.Split('-');

Regex r = new Regex(arr[0] + "(.*)" + arr[1]);
string separator = r.Match(word).Groups[1].Value;  //it gives you the '-'
```